# linker error with a standard deviation function

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I have the following function (in dm.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include "dm.hpp";//calculateStdDev() is declared in the header

double calculateStdDev(const Eigen::VectorXf& input, unsigned int count, double& mean, double& variance, double& stddev) {
    double M = input(0);
    double Q = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int k = 1 ; k < count ; k++) {
        double del = input(k) - M;
        unsigned int j = k + 1;
        Q += k * (del * del) / j;
        M += del / j;
    }
    variance = Q / (count - 1);
    stddev = std::sqrt(variance);
    mean = M;
    return stddev;
}
```

and it is called in my program, test.cpp as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include "dm.hpp"
void regressor::operator()(void) {

    unsigned int rows;
    double meanR, varR, stddevR;
    Eigen::MatrixXf A(rows, cols);
    Eigen::VectorXf b(rows),res(rows);

    for (unsigned int k = 0 ; k < rows; k++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++) {
            A(k,j) = Xb[k][j];
        }
    }
    beta = A.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV).solve(b);
    res = A * beta - b;

    calculateStdDev(res,rows,meanR,varR,stddevR);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
In function `regressor::operator()()':
../../src/algo/test.cpp:55: undefined reference to `calculateStdDev(Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&, unsigned int, double&, double&, double&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my OS is ubuntu (v.10) and when the exact same program is run on cygwin, it works. Does that mean this is a GCC issue. If so, can anyone suggest how to fix it.

EDIT: I am running the following:

```
g++ test.cpp dm.cpp main.cpp -o et -lboost_date_time -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

Comment: How are you compiling your program on Ubuntu?

Comment: just running `g++ test.cpp......-o test -lgsl`

Comment: @user1155299 Do those `......` include all the source files? Especially `dm.cpp` ?

Comment: `#include "dm.hpp";//calculateStdDev() is declared in the header` this line seems wrong. There shouldn't be `;` after include statement. And there shouldn't be any whitespace at the begining.

Comment: that was a typo...fixed it...didn't solve the problem

Comment: could you add the full compilation line you use?

Comment: can you please copy paste the exact syntax you are using for compiling and running

Comment: updated my post with the compilation line

Comment: is calculateStdDev signature in header and cpp file is same?

Comment: yes...what baffles me is the exact same program runs as is on cygwin, and it compiles fine. so it seems to me there is a linker/gcc issue somewhere that I have not been able to spot.